# compute class number of real quadratic field without first computing fundamental unit

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let K be the quadratic field Q(d) with d > 0.
Let u be the fundamental unit, h the class number, R the regulator,
which by definition is abs(log(abs(u))).  The only way I know
to compute u is via the continued fraction expansion of d.  For modestly
sized d this generates very large numbers.  If we know the class 
number then the regulator can be computed (by the class number formula) using ordinary floating point numbers (to that accuracy at least).  Without computing the continued fraction expansion of d,  there is no way that I know of to tell whether the norm of the fundamental unit will be 1 or -1  (well sometimes it can't be -1 for simple reasons, but in general...) and there is no way to compute either the regulator or the class number without first computing the continued fraction expansion.    The question is,  does anybody know a way to get any of this information without computing the continued fraction?

Comment: Find the least integer such that $b^2 \pm 4 \in d \Bbb{Z}^2-0$, then $u = \frac{|-b + \sqrt{b^2 \pm 4}|}{2}$ is the least $u > 1 \in O_K^\times$

Comment: I would accept this as an answer but I don't see that button (and I am indeed logged in).

Comment: While it certainly does answer the question as asked,  unless there's a good way to find the k such that $k^2 d = b^2 \pm 4$,  this method takes even longer than computing the continued fraction.   (I just searched for k.)

Comment: You can't "accept" a comment, Michael – that option is reserved for answers.